# "Getting AR.Drone version..."

Tags: ros, ros-indigo, ardrone-autonomy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone!

I installed Ubuntu Trusty 14.04.5 along with the full version of ROS Indigo named Desktop-Full Install as per http://wiki.ros.org/indigo/Installation/Ubuntu, which uses Gazebo 2.

I then proceeded to add the packages: tum_ardrone, tum_simulator, ardrone_autonomy and ardrone_helpers.

I opened two terminals.
In terminal 1 I ran:

```
source workspace/devel/setup.bash
roscd
export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=$ROS_PACKAGE_PATH:`pwd`/ardrone_autonomy
export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=$ROS_PACKAGE_PATH:`pwd`/ardrone_helpers
export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=$ROS_PACKAGE_PATH:`pwd`/tum_simulator
roslaunch cvg_sim_gazebo ardrone_testworld.launch
```

In terminal 2 I ran:

```
source workspace/devel/setup.bash
roscd
export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=$ROS_PACKAGE_PATH:`pwd`/ardrone_autonomy
export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=$ROS_PACKAGE_PATH:`pwd`/ardrone_helpers
export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=$ROS_PACKAGE_PATH:`pwd`/tum_simulator
export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=$ROS_PACKAGE_PATH:`pwd`/tum_ardrone
```

**Now there are two situations**

**1.** When I run `roslaunch tum_ardrone tum_ardrone.launch`
ROS outputs:

```
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

started roslaunch server http://peterhr:43605/

SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /rosdistro: indigo
 * /rosversion: 1.11.20

NODES
  /
    drone_autopilot (tum_ardrone/drone_autopilot)
    drone_gui (tum_ardrone/drone_gui)
    drone_stateestimation (tum_ardrone/drone_stateestimation)

ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

core service [/rosout] found
ERROR: cannot launch node of type [tum_ardrone/drone_stateestimation]: can't locate node [drone_stateestimation] in package [tum_ardrone]
ERROR: cannot launch node of type [tum_ardrone/drone_autopilot]: can't locate node [drone_autopilot] in package [tum_ardrone]
ERROR: cannot launch node of type [tum_ardrone/drone_gui]: can't locate node [drone_gui] in package [tum_ardrone]
No processes to monitor
shutting down processing monitor...
... shutting down processing monitor complete
```

It creates those 3 Errors that I am not sure how to fix.

**2.** Once that failed I tried running "`rosrun ardrone_autonomy ardrone_driver`" instead which returned the following output on the command line:

```
Wait authentification
Wait authentification
Wait authentification
===================+> 192.168.1.81
Getting AR.Drone version ...
Getting AR.Drone version ...
Getting AR.Drone version ...
```

at which point it continuously loops through "Getting AR.Drone version". Anyone has any idea on how to fix this? I have had a read through a few forums but none of the fixes seemed to work.

I have also tried to run the usual takeoff (`rostopic pub -1 /ardrone/takeoff std_msgs/Empty`), land, flyfoward, etc commands as specified in section 3.3.2 of the following wiki: http://wiki.ros.org/tum_simulator. But that seems to produce no change on my drone simulation whatsoever.

For those whom may think this is helpful for this issue, when I try to run "`telnet 192.168.1.81`", I get the following output:

```
Trying 192.168.1.81...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
```

Please help me out with this, I can't seem to move past this point.
Thanks!

tum_ardrone was cloned from https://github.com/dougvk/tum_simulator (indigo-devel branch).
tum simulator was retrieved from https://github.com/dougvk/tum_simulator.
ardrone_autonomy was installed using the following instructions: http://ardrone-autonomy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/257926/%22getting-ar.drone-version...%22/) by [pratledge](https://answers.ros.org/users/29832/pratledge/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-03-26

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-03-26**:
Are you connected to the AR.Drone's WiFi?

**Comment by [pratledge](https://answers.ros.org/users/29832/pratledge/) on 2017-03-26**:
Hi,
No I don't think so, as I'm not entirely sure how to do that.
But it might be worth pointing out that I'm testing this on a ROS / Gazebo simulation not a physical drone. As that potentially makes a difference...

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-03-26**:
What are using to simulate the drone? `ardrone_autonomy` will provide you with a means of connecting and controlling the drone but it won't simulate one for you.

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-03-28**:
*Exactly* what commands did you run? It's really hard to navigate through slideshare on a phone. Also, note that that slide deck states that it's for ROS Fuerte which was released in 2012.

**Comment by [pratledge](https://answers.ros.org/users/29832/pratledge/) on 2017-03-29**:
Hi, I have updated the question hope this time I have provided enough details! I'm sorry for how slow this is going, it's the first time I've tried to write a question on a Q&A Forum.

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-03-29**:
Did you run `catkin_make` from the root of your workspace after `tum_ardrone`, `tum_simulator`, `ardrone_autonomy`, and `ardrone_helpers` were added to it? It looks like ROS can't find the executables for the nodes in `tum_ardrone`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Because `ardrone_autonomy` stays at `Getting AR.Drone version ...` and when you try to telnet into a drone (that you apparently don't have a physical version of) you get `telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused` it sounds like you need to either:

- get a physical AR.Drone 2.0
- use another ROS package that simulates one

When either of these two conditions are met, then you should be able to start working.

---

Originally posted by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) with karma: 6155 on 2017-03-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pratledge](https://answers.ros.org/users/29832/pratledge/) on 2017-03-27**:
I am simulating the drone using the package tum_simulator, and I have this simulation running on the first terminal while I attempt to control said drone simulation from a second terminal by running the tum_ardrone package's launch files.

**Comment by [pratledge](https://answers.ros.org/users/29832/pratledge/) on 2017-03-27**:
I have also attempted to use the comments such as `rostopic pub -1 /ardrone/takeoff std_msgs/Empty` which says it will send the message in 3 seconds and then stops. It doesn't produce an error or get stuck but it doesn't seem to get the drone moving either.
Source: http://wiki.ros.org/tum_simulator

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-03-27**:
Can you please update your question with everything that you're doing (e.g. launch files used) and the results that you're getting (e.g. terminal output)? I'm going to need more to go on here. Are you running `tum_simulator` then `ardrone_autonomy`, vice versa, etc?

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-03-27**:
Also, please add what version of ROS you're using and what versions of the `tum_simulator` and `ardrone_autonomy` you're using as well. The more information that's given up front, the better help you can be given (and faster too).

**Comment by [pratledge](https://answers.ros.org/users/29832/pratledge/) on 2017-03-28**:
Hi, I have updated the question with the relevant information, please do let me know if I missed out on anything.